# Modify IBM Watson Chatbot Dictionary in php

Tags: ibm-watson

I have just started learning IBM Watson Chatbot.
The problem is that I want to change the Chatbot dictionary using php.
In other words, I want to create a php function that sends question and answers to the IBM Watson API so that it can add them to the dictionary.
But I can't find appropriate document and also the correct API endpoints.
Please help me with doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by add to the dictionary you mean perform crud on entities then you will need the V1 Watson Assistant API - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant#update-entity

In your case you will probably be looking at the update entity method, and update values.